# creating multiple table with single controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am very new to this rails.I have class controller.using class controller i have to create multiple tables.how to create that?Please help.this is my class controller.

```
ClassesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :is_login?
  layout :get_layout

  def new
    @instructor = Instructor.new
    @insfirst = InsFirst.new
    @inssecond = InsSecond.new
  end


  def find
    @instructor = Instructor.new
    @insfirst = InsFirst.new
  end



  def create
    @instructor = Instructor.new(params[:instructor])
    @insfirst = InsFirst.new(params[:insfirst])
    @inssecond = InsSecond.new(params[:inssecond])
    if @instructor.save
      flash[:notice] = "class has been created successfully"
      redirect_to classes_path
    else if @insfirst.save
        flash[:notice] = "class has been created successfully"
         redirect_to classes_path

    end
    render :new
    end
  end


  def index
    @instructors = Instructor.all
    puts "=============="

    @insfirsts = InsFirst.all
    @insseconds = InsSecond.all
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new, I'll give you some help:

> i have to create multiple tables

[You don't `create tables` in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html). You add & read from tables. The tables are just places to store data. What you're really asking is `I need to create *records* in the tables`

Here's how:

```
def create
    @instructor = Instructor.new(instructor_params)
    @insfirst = InsFirst.new(insfirst_params)
    @inssecond = InsSecond.new(inssecond_params)
    if @instructor.save
      flash[:notice] = "class has been created successfully"
      redirect_to classes_path
    else if @insfirst.save
        flash[:notice] = "class has been created successfully"
    end
    redirect_to classes_path
end

private

def instructor_params
    params.require(:class).permit(instructor: [])
end

def insfirst_params
    params.require(:class).permit(insfirst: [])
end

def inssecond_params
    params.require(:class).permit(inssecond: [])
end
```

This assumes you're passing a params hash which looks like:

```
params: {
   class: {
      instructor: [],
      insfirst: [],
      inssecond: []
   }
}
```

---

Something else:

```
  def index
    @instructors = Instructor.all
    puts "=============="

    @insfirsts = InsFirst.all
    @insseconds = InsSecond.all
  end
```

Don't use `puts` in your controller. Rails is [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) - meaning you just use your controller to pass data to your front-end view. You'll use HTML markup in your view to handle the divider you've included:

```
#app/controllers/classes_controller.rb
def index
   @instructors = Instructor.all
   @insfirsts   = InsFirst.all
   @insseconds  = InsSecond.all
end

#app/views/classes/index.html.erb
<%= @instructors.inspect() %>
==============
<%= @insfirsts.inspect() %>
<%= @insseconds.inspect() %>
```